# jQuery Datatable - can I fill div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I am new to the jQuery datatable and am having problem when data returned by the ajax call. How can I use a data set to fill not the table? I need to fill divs. Its structure simmilar to table:

```
  <div id="wrap">
            <div class="drow">                
                <div class="dcol1">
                /*data*/
                </div>
                <div class="dcol2">
                /*data*/
                </div>                       
            </div>
            <div class="drow">                
                <div class="dcol1">
                /*data*/
                </div>
                <div class="dcol2">
                /*data*/
                </div>                       
            </div>
            <div class="drow">                
                <div class="dcol1">
                /*data*/
                </div>
                <div class="dcol2">
                /*data*/
                </div>                       
            </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, basically you want to use dataTables on a `<div>` structure instead of a `<table>` structure? That will never happen.  dataTables continously manipulate the DOM by injecting and removing `<tr>` `<td>` elements, and demands presence of `<tbody>` and `<thead>` if you are not using AJAX or not specify columns. The use of table elements is hardcoded in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the divs like below,

```
$('#wrap .drow').each(function(){
    //populate the dcol1
    $(this).find('.dcol1').text(desiredData);
    //populate the dcol2
    $(this).find('.dcol2').text(desiredData);
});
```

**Need to see the response json structure to help further**.

Now, let you json response has the following structure,

```
{
  data: [
     {
        "dcol1": "some data1",
        "dcol2": "some data1"
     },
     {
        "dcol1": "some data2",
        "dcol2": "some data2"
     },
     .........
     {
        "dcol1": "some dataN",
        "dcol2": "some dataN"
     }         
  ]
}
```

So, you can do it like below,

```
var resp; //your json response
var dataArr = resp.data;
$('#wrap .drow').each(function(index){
     //populate the dcol1
     $(this).find('.dcol1').text(dataArr[index].dcol1);
     //populate the dcol2
     $(this).find('.dcol2').text(dataArr[index].dcol2);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not knowing, how you get response.
But here it is, which may be help you.

```js
$.ajax ({
 type : "GET",
 url : "your web service url",
 cache : false,
 success: function(res) {
     
  $.each(res,function(i, index) {
    var responseObject = res[i];
    $("#wrap").empty(); 
    $("#wrap").append(' <div class="drow"> <div class="dcol1">responseObject.firstName</div><div class="dcol2">responseObject.firstName</div> </div> ');
  });
    //it will loop through your response object and append data as per your format
 },
 error : function(e){
  alert("Something goes wrong");
 }
}); //ajax call ends
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set example for your help, check and let me know if further help required!

Just note that I use return data as **JSON** format.

JSON :

```
[{"drow":[{"dcol1":"dcol1_value","dcol2":"dcol2_value"}]},
{"drow":[{"dcol1":"dcol1_value","dcol2":"dcol2_value"}]}]
```

HTML :

```
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

JQ :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var d= [{"drow":[{"dcol1":"dcol1_value","dcol2":"dcol2_value"}]},
    {"drow":[{"dcol1":"dcol1_value","dcol2":"dcol2_value"}]}];

    //loop over items of d
    $.each(d,function(index, item){
     drowDiv = '';
     dcol1Div = ''; 
     dcol2Div = '';
     $.each(item.drow,function(subIndex, subItem){
      dcol1Div = '<div class="dcol1">' + subItem.dcol1 + '</div>';
      dcol2Div = '<div class="dcol2">' + subItem.dcol2 + '</div>';
      drowDiv = '<div class="drow">' + dcol1Div + dcol2Div + '</div>';
     });

     $("#wrap").append(drowDiv);
    });
});
```

Result:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div class="drow">
                <div class="dcol1">dcol1_value</div>
                <div class="dcol2">dcol2_value</div>
        </div>
        <div class="drow">
                <div class="dcol1">dcol1_value</div>
                <div class="dcol2">dcol2_value</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This stuff also active at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru0bafLc/).